# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in ajax on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sorting, file-get-contents

I am currently working on a `spring project`, and I am designating `uri` using a page controller.
 We need to use `uri short API` now. There is a problem. The way that we're doing it is `PHP`. But I have to use the code in `JavaScript`.

I tried this code.

```js
    data = {};
    data.key = "ehelkhej45jjb38h6f5234234hg";
    data.short = "www.google.com";
    data.name = "googleuri"

    $.ajax({
        url : "https://cutt.ly/api/api.php",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        beforeSend : function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        },
        data : data,
        success : function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

This has caused me an error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cutt.ly/api/api.php' from origin
>   'http://localhost:11000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. jquery-1.9.1.js:8526 POST https://cutt.ly/api/api.php
>   net::ERR_FAILED

I could tried `Postman`

[image: postman]

When I first called this, the `body` was empty and `status : 500Internal Server Error`. But when I call again, I get a `response` like a picture.

And I could tried `GET` and `jsonp` but it was Blocked

```js
    $.ajax({
        url : "https://cutt.ly/api/api.php",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        data : data,
        success : function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

**Block ERROR**

> jquery-1.9.1.js:8336 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked
>   cross-origin response
>   https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?callback=jQuery191049576531804679713_1565245716711&key=ehelkhej45jjb38h6f5234234hg&short=www.google.com&name=googleuri&_=1565245716712
>   with MIME type text/html. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

What I've tried. It was worked. But it is error

> GET
>   http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=ehelkhej45jjb38h6f5234234hg&short=redisgate.kr&name=redisgate
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

```js
var options = "https://cutt.ly/api/api.php?key=ehelkhej45jjb38h6f5234234hg&short=www.google.com&name=googleuri"


$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
        if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
          var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
          options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
          }
        });

$.get(
    options,
         function (response) {
             console.log("> ", response);
});
```

[This link](https://cutt.ly/cuttly-api) is the link that has API usage. How can you solve this problem?

Comment: You're getting the CORS error on the POST probably because that API doesn't support POSTs. You're getting the CORB error when you're trying the GET in jQuery because that API is responding to your GET with content-type `text/html` when it should be responding (probably) with type `application/json`. Your browser will block `text/html` from a cross-origin request as a security measure. It looks like that API was really only intended to be used server-side.

Comment: @Phil I solved the error by referring to the answers you linked, but there is no return value. Why?

Comment: @BenChamberlin I edited out the question. There's a code I've corrected for the error, but it doesn't give me any response value. What is the reason?

Comment: When I run your updated example, I get `{"url":{"status":4}}`. Seems like the proxy runs really slow sometimes (took 8 seconds for me a couple times). If that's what you're seeing after the proxy is done, the api key is invalid.

Comment: @BenChamberlin  Look at my question. Error waiting for response value. The key value is incorrect for you to see the result like that way.